# Cannot implicitly convert type object to System.Reflection.Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Please help me to fix this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Reflection.Assembly'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Thank you!!!

**CODE**

```
var assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(assemblyPath);

var ads = new AppDomainSetup
               {
                  ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase, 
                  DisallowCodeDownload = true 
               };

AppDomain newDomainName = AppDomain.CreateDomain("newDomainName", null, ads);

Assembly testLibrary = newDomainName.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assemblyName.Name,
                      typeof(System.Windows.Controls.UserControl).Name);  // Here the error occures
```

Comment: try correcting the parenthesis matching typeof(System.Windows.Controls.UserControl).Name) you are missing an opening paranthesis EX: typeof((System.Windows.Controls.UserControl).Name)

Comment: @Freeman No, the parentheses are correct. The first closing parenthesis belongs to `typeof`, the second is the closing parenthesis for `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You appear to be creating a `UserControl` in a new domain, and then store it in a variable of type `Assembly`. That doesn't make sense to me. Edit: in addition to that, you're not passing the assembly name of the assembly that contains the `UserControl` type, so it wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: The return value from `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` isn't an `Assembly`. So why have you declared `testLibrary` as being one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CreateInstanceAndUnwrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b223a08k.aspx) returns an instance of the created type (`System.Windows.Controls.UserControl` in the code above), not an `Assembly`. The code should be:

```
UserControl userControl = (UserControl) newDomainName.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
    assemblyName.Name, typeof(System.Windows.Controls.UserControl).Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `FullName` property:

```
typeof(System.Windows.Controls.UserControl).FullName
```

EDIT:

Also try assemblyName.FullName

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c4f1xde.aspx) both should be full names.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Object CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
    string assemblyName,
    string typeName)
```

It returns an object and you need an Assembly, please recheck.

Comment: "and you need a Type" -- Huh? `testLibrary` is declared as having type `Assembly`.